# Error in if (x == "" | x == ".") { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r

I have a questions regarding an error I get. I am new to R so bear with me.

I do understand that the second error is probably an effect of the first error, but I do not understand the first error? Do anyone have any ideas why it occurs?

```
 #### Correction of snow surface roughness with slope ####
> 
> f <- list.files(pattern=paste("ruggedness", i_max, ".asc$", sep=""), full.names=TRUE)
> rugg<- raster(f)
Error in if (x == "" | x == ".") { : argument is of length zero
> 
> if (i_max > 1) { 
+   
+   
+   f <- list.files(pattern=paste("slope", i_max, ".asc$", sep=""), full.names=TRUE)
+   slp_coef <- as.matrix(raster(f))
+   slp_coef <- 1- ((slp_coef-30)/30)
+   slp_coef[slp_coef < 0] <- 0
+   slp_coef[slp_coef > 1] <- 1
+   slp_coef <- 1 + (slp_coef * (i_max -1))
+   slp_coef <- round(slp_coef, digits = 0)
+   #write.ascii.grid(data = slp_coef, "coef", header = head, write.header = TRUE, digits = 2,
+   #                hdr.digits = 3 , dec = ".", georef = "corner")
+   
+   
+   for (i in 1:(i_max -1)) {
+     f <- list.files(pattern=paste("ruggedness", i, ".asc$", sep=""), full.names=TRUE)
+     rugg_i<- raster(f)
+     rugg[which(slp_coef == i )] <- rugg_i[which(slp_coef == i)]
+   }
+ }
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': argument is of length zero
```

Thank you,
Liza

I am trying to get potential release areas for avalanches by using Rstudio and RSAGA, so everything is helpful!

Comment: My *guess* is that f is an empty vector, because there's no file with that particular pattern in the working directory. If not, there's something specific about the format of that file, and it'll be hard to work out what without seeing it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it does sound logical, although it still produces files for me during earlier commands, which I think is weird during my. I think it all comes down to that I have troubles to set rsaga.env, 

I get the errorcode:

`Error in if (file.exists(file.path(saga.path, "modules"))) { :`

I really do not understand how to find "the modules", do you have any helpful tips?